# Unable to install json-regex-difftool

Tags: python, pip

I tried the link below, but was not able to install this package.

I got the following error:

> E: Unable to locate package json-regex-difftool-0.1
>   E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'json-regex-difftool-0.1'

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/json-regex-difftool/0.1

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify the version number that way. Simply use

```
$ pip install json-regex-difftool
```

You can check for its existence using `pip search`

```
$ pip search json-regex-difftool
json-regex-difftool     - A tool for doing a comparison or difference of JSON documents with regular expression support
```

If you specifically want version 0.1 you can specify that on the command line

```
$ pip install json-regex-difftool==0.1
```